# Flutter notification not coming in device but in console its showing

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implement an FCM in flutter but issue is its not coming notification in device. I can see notification tile and body in console. I know I need to close the app for getting notification but when I close the app its still not coming and when I open app again and check in console I can see the notification. [image]

You can see when app open then its showing me console title and body. I am not sending when app is open. App is Closed but when its opening then its showing in console -_-

Comment: If its simulator you are using notification will not be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

When the app is open it will not show you the notification you will need to control that part and show a widget in your App (I would recomend to use Overlay and the notifications will be visible in your App above all your widgets). The json changes from iOS and Android so you should create to json mapping in the two cases.

You need to check if the permissions are granted in iOS and you should request the permissions so the user can accept it and receive the notifications. You can request the permissions with this code in the appDelegate:

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { granted, error in
        
        // Enable or disable features based on the authorization.
    }
```

You should test in real device because sometimes the emulator is not working correctly to test notifications.

Comment: Issue is its not  showing also when app is closed. But when is open then its showing in console only

Comment: Yes, when the app is opened you should control it in your onMessage you should use for example Overlay and create your widget to show your notification in your App. When the app is not in foreground your notifications will not show correctly if the permissions is not accepted by the user so with the code I added the notifications will be asked when the app is opened, but sometimes it doesn't work correctly on the simulator and I would recommend to use a real device for the testing when it's not in foreground

Answer (score 0):

From **[Firebase Apple integration](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration/)** ,

> For iOS; you must have a physical iOS device to receive messages.
> Firebase Cloud Messaging integrates with the Apple Push Notification service (APNs), however APNs only works with real devices.

**But you can try this replacement in your `info.plist` file .**

Replace `<false/>` by `<string>0</string>`

**Before :**

[image]

**Now :**

[image]

> **Info :** If you don't have this code in your info.plist and you don't
> receive the notification as well, make sure you add it.

Don't forget , here is the new code :

```
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
<string>0</string>
```

Hope that it will be useful